# Return JSON object with a "header"

Tags: python, json, api

I have an API, where I need to return data. I want to make a "header", where I specify the amount of tutors, the call returned. My current function looks like this:

```
def get_matching_tutors(filters):
formatted_tutors = []

matching_tutors = [tutor for tutor in tutor_list if matches_all_filters(filters, tutor)]

matching_tutors = sorted(matching_tutors, key = lambda i: i['hours'])
matching_tutors = sorted(matching_tutors, key = lambda i: i['tutor_amount_of_students'])

for tutor in matching_tutors:
    data = {
        "first_name": tutor["first_name"],
        "last_name": tutor["last_name"],
        "mobile_phone": tutor["mobile_phone"],
        "email": tutor["email"],
        "status": tutor["status"],
        "more_courses": tutor["more_courses"],
        "hours": tutor["hours"],
        "tutor_amount_of_students": tutor["tutor_amount_of_students"],
        "teachworks": tutor["teachworks"]
    }
    formatted_tutors.append(data)
return jsonify(formatted_tutors)
```

This is an example, of the response.

```
[
{
    "email": "TEST@test.dk",
    "first_name": "TEST",
    "hours": 0,
    "last_name": "TEST",
    "mobile_phone": "",
    "more_courses": "Yes",
    "status": "Active",
    "teachworks": "https://toptutors.teachworks.com/employees/114106",
    "tutor_amount_of_students": 3
},
{
    "email": "Jeppe6721@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "Jeppe",
    "hours": 28.0,
    "last_name": "Vestergaard Nielsen",
    "mobile_phone": "51781003",
    "more_courses": "Yes",
    "status": "Active",
    "teachworks": "https://toptutors.teachworks.com/employees/133813",
    "tutor_amount_of_students": 3
},
{
    "email": "sidra200265@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "Sidra",
    "hours": 52.0,
    "last_name": "Ahmed",
    "mobile_phone": "52111671",
    "more_courses": "Yes",
    "status": "Active",
    "teachworks": "https://toptutors.teachworks.com/employees/133751",
    "tutor_amount_of_students": 3
}
```

]

I'd like to add a header, that specifies the amount of tutors/arrays that the response returned. So it would be at the top of the json response, "amount_of_tutors": (Amount)

Comment: you mean response header or just an extra key in the JSON?

Comment: isn't publishing phone numbers and emails a violation of the privacy of those people? This is just fake data that you are putting as an example right?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki They aren't real people.

Comment: @buran An extra key. But I only want there to be 1, at the top.

Comment: You don't need a "header" that gives you the number of items in the array you're about to return. The client can count the number of items received with exactly zero effort. Don't add complexity where none is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to add this line after the loop and change the return statement:

```
my_response = {'amount_of_tutors':len(formatted_tutors), 'tutors':formatted_tutors}
return jsonify(my_response)
```

But it is doubtful whether there is benefit having that extra key.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the "header" be the first item in `formatted_tutors`:

```
formatted_tutors = []
formatted_tutors.append({"amount_of_tutors": 0})
```

Then after the loop is finished, go back and update the "header" to contain the real number:

```
formatted_tutors[0]["amount_of_tutors"] = real_amount_of_tutors
```

But really, this seems unnecessary.  What is the point of this extra header?  Anyone calling this API will have to fully parse the json response, at which point they can just use `len()` to see how many tutors were returned.  I don't see how the extra header is helpful.

Comment: This adds it as it's own kind of item, I want it to be in it's own "array", if you know what I mean.

Comment: So it stands out more. Like this:

[
{
amount of students
}
{
tutor info
}
]

Comment: @Sonny No, I don't know what you mean.  If you have a specific json format in mind, please put it in the question.  Otherwise we're just guessing what you want.